# Problems using Powershell/curl to check http headers

Tags: powershell, curl, command-prompt

This is turning out to be way more difficult than I thought (and than it probably should be).

I've tried Cygwin+curl, but that fails to run (Cygwin can never find curl.exe, but I did do a package check and it's there).

I've tried curl for Windows, using the command prompt, and it works. But I have quite a few urls to check and doing them individually just isn't time efficient. I can't figure out how to tell curl, through cmd prompt, to use a file (since there's no "xargs") like mentioned [here](http://www.christopheryee.org/bulk-url-checker-curl/).

I've also tried using PowerShell, but that's also being problematic. When I try to follow option 1 [here](http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/08/query-http-status-codes-and-headers.html)

I get an error when I try running `$xHTTP.open("GET",$url,$false)`:

> Exception calling "open" with "3" argument(s): "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))"

Also with PowerShell, I have absolutely no idea how to get it to use a file containing urls. My knowledge of PS is very very limited (as in non-existent).

What would be nice here would be to figure out how to get the command prompt/curl to use a file, but I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a more direct way to do this with PowerShell V3:

```
PS> Get-Content .\urls.txt
http://www.cnn.com
http://www.msn.com

PS> Get-Content urls.txt | Foreach { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -Method HEAD }

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           :
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Vary: Accept-Encoding
                    Connection: Keep-Alive
                    Cache-Control: max-age=60, private
                    Content-Type: text/html
                    Date: Tue, 08 Jan 2013 20:21:46 GMT
                    Expires: Tue, 08 Jan 2013 20:22:46 GMT...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Vary, Accept-Encoding], [Connection, Keep-Alive], [Cache-Control, max-age=60, private],
                    [Content-Type, text/html]...}
...
```

To handle 404's use a try/catch e.g.:

```
PS> Get-Content urls.txt | 
        Foreach {try {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -Method HEAD} catch { "Oops - $_"}}
```

To redirect to a file, this works for me:

```
PS> Get-Content urls.txt | 
        Foreach {try {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_ -Method HEAD} catch { "Oops - $_"}} > 
        $home\Desktop\foo.txt
```

Comment: Couple questions about this (but for the most parts it's exactly what I was looking for).

Is there a way to gracefully do something with 404s? Right now, a 404 ends up with an exception.

I'm trying to output it to a file, using -OutFile .\Desktop\results.txt. It creates the file, but it's empty. I'm clearly missing something, but not sure what.

Comment: Keith, thank you very very much. I did make a slight addition, to get just the status code (I know I didn't ask for that, but at least I managed to figure _that_ part out. `| Select StatusCode` after the `}}`). I will ask one final thing: I noticed that it's retrieving the final status code rather than any intermediates, like 301/302s. Nothing on the "Invoke-WebRequest" MS TechNet page stood out to me that suggested how to do that. Is this possible (to get it to stop at a 301, rather than following it on to the final result?

Comment: @Braffin Use the `-MaximumRedirection` parameter with a value of 0.

Comment: Keith, I've been trying to figure out how to use that parameter, but everything I've found elsewhere online says it's part of the "New-PSSessionOption" cmdlet. So far the only way I've gotten the code to run is by appending `;New-PSSessionOption -MaximumRedirection 0` to the above code, but then that just simply writes the maximumredirection output to the console and doesn't really seem to accomplish anything.

Comment: It's a parameter on Invoke-WebRequest as well.  Of course, that doesn't mean that it works as advertised.  Have you tried `iwr -url $_ -Method Head -MaximumRedirection 0`?

Comment: I tried adding that, but nothing happens (it runs and the file is created, but there's nothing in it and no errors in the console). So I played around with it; if I take our the iwr (which by the way I have no idea what it does) and change `-url` back to `-Uri` everything works for the most part. I get the 1st response code in a file as I want. There is a message in the console about the max # of redirects being exceeded, but I can live with it since it doesn't stop the code. I have more questions, but I'll try to figure them out. If I get stuck I'll create a new question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Braffin `iwr` is just an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`.  Sorry about the -Url\Uri confusion - it should have been -Uri.  BTW this works for me. I just tested it on a redirect.aspx page I set up a long time ago.  Setting MaximumRedirection to 0 gives me back a 302 response and the headers for the first hop and not subsequent redirections.  Although I do get an error which I then suppressed with the parameter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue.

Comment: Ah, makes sense that `iwr` is just `Invoke-WebRequest` ;). I was putting `iwr` AND `Invoke-WebRequest` together. I tried with only `iwr` and it does indeed work just fine. (and thanks for the `-ErrorAction...`)